# Books about JSON

Tags: mysql, json

Why isn't there any books on JSON on Amazon, which would mean there isn't a book about JSON in the world. I wasn't able to find anything with just the title JSON, it was either a chapter in an AJAX book or JavaScript book!

Basically I need some sound foundation on the JSON, and how it communicates with MySQL db, with the help of PHP most likely. Any books for that or a marathon of tutorials site?

Comment: What on Earth are you talking about?  JSON is an acronym for "JavaScript Object Notation", so of course it will be contained within a book on JavaScript.  An object notation cannot be used to communicate with anything, let alone a database: it is merely a means of encoding/representing data.  If you want to pass JSON encoded data to/from a database using PHP, then [a book on AJAX+PHP](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=php%20ajax&sprefix=php+aja%2Cstripbooks&rh=i%3Astripbooks%2Ck%3Aphp%20ajax) is almost certainly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As above comments suggest, JSON is pretty much an array of javascript, which you can use it to store information like XML.

As a book reference, you will definitely love this one;

[http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-JSON-Essentials-Srinivas-Sriparasa/dp/1783286032/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1391667175&sr=8-1&keywords=json+essentials](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1783286032)

Answer (score 0):

JSON is just a datatype, similar to XML (but XML is way more powerfull).

I doubt you'll find a whole book dedicated to JSON because there just isn't that much to say.

JSON itself cannot communicate with a MySQL database, PHP can.